# preg_replace apply string function (like urlencode) in replacement

Tags: php, preg-replace

i want to parse all links in html document string in php in such way: replace href='LINK' to href='MY_DOMAIN?URL=LINK', so because LINK will be url parameter it must be urlencoded. i'm trying to do so:

```
preg_replace('/href="(.+)"/', 'href="http://'.$host.'/?url='.urlencode('${1}').'"', $html);
```

but '${1}' is just string literal, not founded in preg url, what need i do, to make this code working?

Comment: Oh God... here we go again...

Comment: Would you be willing to entertain non-regex solutions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, to answer your question, you have two choices with Regex.

You can use the [`e` modifier](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to the regex, which tells `preg_replace` that the replacement is php code and should be executed.  This is typically seen as not great, since it's really no better than eval...

```
preg_replace($regex, "'href=\"http://{$host}?url='.urlencode('\\1').'\"'", $html);
```

The other option (which is better IMHO) is to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$callback = function ($match) use ($host) {
    return 'href="http://'.$host.'?url='.urlencode($match[1]).'"';
};
preg_replace_callback($regex, $callback, $html);
```

But also never forget, [don't parse HTML with regex](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)...

So in practice, the better way of doing it (The more robust way), would be:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$aTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($aTags as $aElement) {
    $href = $aElement->getAttribute('href');
    $href = 'http://'.$host.'?url='.urlencode($href);
    $aElement->setAttribute('href', $href);
}
$html = $dom->saveHtml();
```

Comment: just $aElement->setAttribute($href); must be replaced on $aElement->setAttribute('href', $href);

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'e' modifier.

```
preg_replace('/href="([^"]+)"/e',"'href=\"http://'.$host.'?url='.urlencode('\\1').'\"'",$html);
```

http://uk.php.net/preg-replace - example #4